# Hardcoded Query in PetaPoco ORM

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orm, petapoco

We are planning to use PetaPoco in our project. As it is tiny ORM with performance benefit, one of the thing worried me a lot is hard coded queries.

Due to that, whenever our column changes (added/removed), we have issue to find out same in all the queries.

Can we generate Columnname in tt file and use that in place of hard coded query something like:

```
"Select * from " + Tables.Customer + " Where " + CustomerTable.CustomerId + " = 1"
```

Comment: It's not in the Petapoco project scope and it will be a royal PITA to maintain. Try to use good naming conventions for your tables and you are good.

Comment: I do not understand royal PITA.

Comment: Will be too hard to develop day to day.

Comment: You should look into NPoco (a PetaPoco fork) that (I think) implements a Linq provider, so you can make statically linked queries https://github.com/schotime/NPoco/wiki/Simple-LINQ-Queries /cc @schotime

Comment: True. But what about Performance and Support/Updates?